# Copy Paste VBA Code Has Blank Rows

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

The below code searches, copies & pastes the found data into another worksheet. However, there are blanks when this is done in the pasted worksheet. Eg: Found "To Be Copied" in Cell A1 and copied the entire row to the specified worksheet. Found "To Be Copied" in A4 and copied the entire row to the specified worksheet. However, there are two blank rows in the pasted sheet between A1 and A4. Thanks for your help.

```
Sub Deleting()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim wsh As Worksheet, i As Long, Endr As Long, x1 As Worksheet, p As Long
    Set wsh = ActiveSheet
    Worksheets.Add(Before:=Worksheets("Original Sheet")).Name = "Skipped"
    Set x1 = Worksheets("Skipped")
    Worksheets("ABC").Activate
    i = 2
    Endr = wsh.Range("A" & wsh.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    While i <= Endr
        If Cells(i, "A") = "To Be Copied" Then
            wsh.Rows(i).Copy
            x1.Rows(i).PasteSpecial
            p = p + 1
            Endr = Endr + 1
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Properly indenting your code will make it much easier for everyone (including yourself) to read and understand your code. I did it for you this time.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett Corbett Thanks, Will keep this in mind the next time on :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your existing code needs either

1. A separate counter for the written row position (Cutter's point), or
2. Pasting to the last used row of "Skipped" using `xlUp` to find the last used cell

But better still would be copying the rows in a single shot using `AutoFilter`. Something like below

```
Sub Quicker()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim rng1 As Range
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set ws1 = Sheets("ABC")
Set ws2 = Worksheets.Add(Before:=Worksheets("Original Sheet"))
'in case Skipped exists
On Error Resume Next
ws2.Name = "Skipped"
On Error GoTo 0
ws1.AutoFilterMode = False
Set rng1 = ws1.Range(ws1.[a1], ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
rng1.AutoFilter 1, "To Be Copied"
If rng1.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count > 1 Then
    Set rng1 = rng1.Offset(1, 0).Resize(rng1.Rows.Count - 1)
    rng1.EntireRow.Copy ws2.[a1]
End If
ws1.AutoFilterMode = False
MsgBox "Sheet " & ws2.Name & " updated"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

You need two counters: `i` for the source rows, `j` for the destination rows. You only increment `j` when a row is copied.

Comment: +1 Otherwise your destination is always going to relate exactly to your source